# Trying to make a train in Unity but having some problems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

So hi guys. I'm trying to make a train in Unity. I created an empty objects with cubes which contains the data of Transforms to which train should ride. Everything is working nicely but I have such a problem. While riding train "twitches" several times and I really can't understand why it is happening. If somebody can help what to do I'll be very glad to hear your answers.

TrainMovement.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewTrainMovemnt : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public GameObject waypointContainer;
    public AnimationCurve startCurve;
    private Vector3[] waypoints = new Vector3[30];
    public int currentWaypoint = 0;
    public float speed = 0.0F;
    public float currentSpeed;
    public int direction = 0;
    public int acceleration = 0;
    public float acc = 0;
    private float startTime;
    public Vector3 movementVector;
    public float damping;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < waypointContainer.transform.childCount; i++) 
        {
            waypoints[i] = waypointContainer.transform.GetChild(i).transform.position;
            Debug.Log(waypoints[i]);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("e")) 
        {
            acceleration++;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("q")) 
        {
            acceleration--;
        }

        if (acceleration==-1)
            acc=-0.001F;
        if (acceleration==-2)
            acc=-0.002F;
        if (acceleration==-3)
            acc=-0.003F;
        if (acceleration < -3) 
        {
            acceleration = -3;
        }
        if (acceleration==0)
            acc=0.0F;
        if (acceleration==1)
            acc=0.001F;
        if (acceleration==2)
            acc=0.002F;
        if (acceleration==3)
            acc=0.003F;
        if (acceleration > 3) 
        {
            acceleration = 3;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < waypointContainer.transform.childCount; i++) 
        {
            MoveToWaypoint();
            startTime = Time.time + 2.0F;
        }
    }

    void MoveToWaypoint() 
    {
        currentSpeed += startCurve.Evaluate((Time.time - startTime)/10)*acc;

        float currentStep = currentSpeed * Time.smoothDeltaTime;

        movementVector = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.transform.position, waypoints[currentWaypoint], currentStep);
        Debug.Log(movementVector);
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, movementVector);
        float distance_ = Vector3.Distance(this.transform.position, waypoints[currentWaypoint]);

        if (currentStep - distance > 0.001) 
        {
            currentWaypoint += direction;
            if (currentWaypoint >= 0 && currentWaypoint < waypointContainer.transform.childCount) 
            {
                movementVector = Vector3.MoveTowards(this.transform.position,waypoints[currentWaypoint], currentStep);
            }

            if (distance_ == 0f) 
            {
                currentWaypoint++;
            }
        }
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        this.transform.position = movementVector;

        damping = 3.5f;

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(waypoints[currentWaypoint] - this.transform.position);
        this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(this.transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping);
    }
}
```

An example of "twithcing": https://youtu.be/7xVMVrxbbgw

Comment: I would not accept input inside of the Physics function `FixedUpdate()`. If you want to move your train in that function, that is fine. You should utilize `Update()` for input.

Comment: why do you call `MoveToWaypoint` in a for loop for all waipoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated before, Input should not be done in the FixedUpdate() loop. That is for Physics calculation.

To fix the Twitching, I would suggest to move those Input checks out of the fixed update, Lerp the movement between nodes, and change that large IF block to a Switch Statement. Doing all that in updates is very inefficient.

Comment: So I used some of your pieces of advice. Maybe it helped me to optimize my code. But they didn't helped me to solve the problem. The solution was to correct positions of cubes in a right way. So now I have a workable code. Thanks I guess

Comment: You are welcome! That sort of problem can be symptom of many things. Glad I can help.